# I use os.system to run executable file, but it need a .so file, it can't find library

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, dynamic-library

When I call a executable in python using `os.system("./mydemo")` in Ubuntu, it can't find the .so file (libmsc.so) needed for mydemo. I used `os.system("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=pwd:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;")`, but it still can't find libmsc.so.

The libmsc.so is in the current directory. and shouldn't be global.

Comment: First, why are you using `os.system` in the first place? [Its own docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) say "The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `os.system("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=pwd:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;")`, you run new instance of shell, alter `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` there than immediately exit from it. Also, pwd mean nothing in the context of Python.

Try to set env variables like this:

```
os.system("LD_LIBRARY_PATH={} ./mydemo".format(os.getcwd()))
```

Or maybe it is better to use subprocess module?

```
import subprocess
env = os.environ.copy()
env['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = os.getcwd()
proc = subprocess.Popen("./mydemo", shell=True, env=env)
proc.wait()
```

Comment: Why use `shell=True` here?

Comment: @abarnert: Backward compability with `os.system` :)

Comment: THANK YOU!!! you guys are amazing!! I struggle with the problem for 2 days!!! thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, executing `export ...` via `os.system` will only set that shell variable within the scope, thus it's not available in the following `os.system` scopes. You should set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the shell, before executing the Python script.

Btw. also avoid setting relative paths…

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `export` only exports its variables to children of the current shell. As in the shell that you created by calling `os.system`, which then immediately exits.

If you want the simplest fix to make this work, you can do both the `export` and the target program inside a single shell:

```
os.system("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=pwd:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; ./mydemo")
```

There are some other problems with this. For example, `export`ing and assigning a variable in the same command is a `bash`-ism that may not be available in all shells. With [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) you can specify a specific shell, but with `system` you just get whatever the OS considers the default shell—on Linux, the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) says this means `/bin/sh -c`.

Really, the best way to solve this is to just not use a shell in the first place, and set the environment variables the way you want. That's exactly why the [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) docs say: "The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function." For example:

```
env = dict(os.environ)
env['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '"{}":{}'.format(
    os.getcwd(), env.get('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', ''))
subprocess.check_call(['./mydemo'], env=env)
```

Or, if you want to be really safe (unlike your shell code):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = env.get('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', '')
if LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH = ':' + LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = shlex.quote(os.getcwd()) + LD_LIBRARY_PATH
subprocess.check_call(['./mydemo'], env=env)
```

I've written this out more explicitly and verbosely than you'd normally write it, to make the steps obvious: don't include a trailing `:` before an empty path, and use `shlex.quote` in case someone does something tricky with the current working directory.

Comment: > `env['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = ...` < If variable is empty (which is most likely), you will get "path:" which is insecure (it seeks for so's in _current_ directory). Not the OPs, case, but if `./mydemo` chdirs to another directory and runs some binary then...

Comment: @myaut: It's modifying the environment in exactly the same way his shell code intended to. And notice that he's explicitly _trying_ to set it to the current directory, so… Anyway, _not_ doing the `:` and current value means that if the variable _isn't_ empty, you'll erase any existing paths, which could break `mydemo` (or some other program it spawns).